# Create a new post from template as part of a script

Tags: r, blogdown

I'm trying to create a new post each week programatically. I want to create an Rmd file from a template that I can pass parameters to and then have `blogdown::serve_site()` render it properly.

I've tried using `rmarkdown::render` and can basically get it to do what I want by rendering a HTML file. But I'd like to have this somehow part of my `blogdown::serve_site()` process.

This is an example of what I can do using `rmarkdown::render()`.

First, create a template Rmd file as below.

```r
author: James Day
params: 
  week: 1
  year: 2019
```

The week is `r params$week` and the year is `r params$year`

Some code to process data using params

```
library(dplyr)
data <- tibble(week = 1:52, 
               year = 2019,
               num = runif(52))

data_for_report <- data %>%
  filter(week >= params$week & year == params$year)

print(data_for_report)
# some other code.....
```

If I save that file as `test.Rmd` then the following code will render this as HTML with the supplied params.

```r
render_blog_post = function(fname, week, year) {
  rmarkdown::render(
    fname,  
    params = list(week = week, year = year),
    output_file = paste0(year, "-week-", week, "-report.html"),
    output_options = list(pandoc_args = c(paste0("--metadata=title:\"Week ", week, " Report\""),
                                          paste0("--metadata=slug:\"", year, "-week-", week, "-report\"")
                                          )
                          )
    )
}


render_blog_post("test.Rmd",  week = 10, year = 2019)
```

This HTML file is what I want but obviously I want this to be part of my workflow for creating a new blog post.

I'm wondering how I could use a similar workflow to create an Rmd from a template using blogdown?

Essentially, in my weekly script I would like to

1. Create a new Rmd file from a template
2. Adjust the YAML of the newly created Rmd file using paramaters I supply to a function
3. Save this .Rmd in the `./content/posts` folder of my blogdown project
4. Render the Rmd file with `blogdown::serve_site()`

Comment: If you want this to automatically work with `blogdown::serve_site()`, you may have to look into [a custom build script](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/methods.html#methods)

Comment: I'm doing similar things, what I did was writing a bunch of R scripts to generate the plain .md posts for a blogdown/hugo site, and hook them up in a crontab job.